# Undefined function error javascript

Tags: javascript

Maybe I'm being completely stupid, but with the following simple function, I am told there is a reference error, with isEven being undefined:

```
var isEven = function(number) {
    if (number%2=0) {
        return true;
    }
    else {
        return false;
    };
};
```

Is there something that I've missed that I'm doing wrong?

Comment: It's probably a scope problem. You defined the function in one scope, and try to call it in a different scope. You need to show more context to determine this.

Comment: `number%2==0` (two ==)

Comment: Or it could be the typo that @thg435 pointed out. If you get a syntax error, the function won't be defined.

Comment: ah yeah it was the single = that was the problem, cheers

Comment: Didn't that report a syntax error in the Javascript console? Chrome says _Invalid left-hand side in assignment_

Answer (score 1):

You're using an assignment operation in the if clause, and not an equality check, you'll want to change the second line from

`number % 2 = 0`

to this:

`(number % 2) == 0`

The error you mentioned is happening because you would get an initial error detailing the improper syntax, but if you ignore that and still try to call the function it will tell you it was never defined (because during the definition there was an error).

Comment: It will cause a syntax error, but if he ignores that error and tries to call the function anyway, he'll get the undefined function error.

Answer (score 0):

Your if statement uses "=" instead of "==" or "===",
which means you are trying to assign number%2 the value of zero.
Use == or === instead to compare.

```
var isEven = function(number) {
    if (number%2===0) {
        return true;
    }
    else {
        return false;
    };
};
```

Answer (score 0):

(=) Assigns Value and (==) Compares the value

```
var isEven = function(number) {
if ((number%2)==0)
          return true;
else  
          return false;
};
```

Step 1 :

```
(number % 2)
```

Take's out the remainder when divided by two

Step 2

```
(number % 2) == 0
```

Compares if remainder is equal to zero.